# Showing Ribbon Tabs after changing display in CSS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm the main administrator for my employer's SharePoint 2013 site, and recently I've run into a problem that I'm unable to correct.

At the request of one of the administrators to prevent people from editing pages, I found out how to remove the Browse and Page ribbon tab display.

Unforuntunately, the added side effect of this is when  person with contribute rights needs to upload a new document or edit a list, they can't because the tabs are gone!

As a full administrator I can see them when I am in edit mode of a page, but I must zoom in to about 330% and select a very thin portion of the colored tab I want to go into.

I've gone back into my css to see if I can set display:none back to display:block, but I'm unable to find the correct control or class to get this to display properly.

I've included a screen capture demonstrating this, and one in developer mode also.

[image: Zoomed in Ribbon Tabs Image].

[image: Developer Console Image]

If there's anything else I can provide that would be helpful, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the advice and assistance imoses and James Malcolm.  I plan on using your suggestions to properly limit permissions for different users/groups in the future.

A colleague and I were able to sort out how to get the Browse and Ribbon tabs available yesterday morning.

We ended up scanning the CSS from the master css file, and one of the Corev15 CSS files.  My colleague found a UL class (*ms-cui-tts*) in div *ms-cui-topBar2* that contained the LI *ms-cui-tt-span* which had been set as *display:none*.

Changing this to *display:block* made the ribbon tabs visible again, and then we lowered a margin (*ms-cui-tt-a*) by a few pixels.

I'm not sure why those two things were affected by the previous edit of the s4ribbonRow div set to display:none, but it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this by relying on SharePoint's built-in permissions settings.  If a user has read-only access to a page, they won't be able to Edit it.  If a user has Contribute access to a page, they can use the ribbon normally.

Using permissions in this way also prevents people from appending this text to the page URL to circumvent the Edit button and put the page into edit mode:

```
?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for specific elements:

Edit - `#Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit-SelectedItem`

Check Out - `#Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Checkout-Large`

Paste/Clipboard - `#Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Clipboard-LargeMedium-0-0`

Font - `#Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font.FontColor-Small`

The parent element to all of these is `#Ribbon.WikiPageTab` or `#Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab` when in edit mode.

If you're looking to restrict edit access you could simply use page permissions or alternatively, use a second stylesheet (lower in the cascade) that reverts these visibility changes, but only give admins/designers access to the second stylesheet.